# Tratar Null con ExecuteScalar cuando se evalua con datos tipo DATETIME

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola Estoy trabajando en C# y SQL Server me surgió la duda de como validar el ultimo registro de entrada de un trabajador con la siguiente instruccion:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CAST( max(registroEntrada )as date) as registroEntrada FROM usuarios WHERE numTrabajador = '"+txtTrabajador.Text+"'", conexion);
```

donde quiero evaluar que si el día de su ultimo registro corresponde al mismo día que quiere hacer el registro con:

```
var dias = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Investigando un poco encontré que al utilizar ExecuteScalar podria guarda la fecha en una variable y para poder comparar de la siguiente manera:

```
if(resultado.ToString() == dias)
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("Verifica que tengas una entrada  activa.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entrada  activa.");
               
            }
```

Cuando ingreso un numero valido al evaluar me manda directo al bloque if aun teniendo una respuesta con datos validos del sql pero si cambio de la siguiente manera

```
if(resultado.ToString() != dias)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entrada  activa.");
               
            }
            else
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("Verifica que tengas una entrada  activa.");
            }
```

Entra al bloque if aun no teniendo una entrada activa, no se cual podría ser el error ya que todo lo regresa en null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando compares fechas debes hacerlo con el tipo `date` en ambos lados de la igualdad, de otra forma, si comparas `string` te llevarás muchos disgustos, y más tratando con valores ocasionales `null`.

Dicho esto, creo que lo más sencillo es delegar a la sentencia sql la validación, comparando la fecha de la última entrada con la fecha de hoy:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) 
FROM usuarios
WHERE CAST(max(registroEntrada) as date) = CAST(getdate() as date)
FROM usuarios WHERE numTrabajador = '"+txtTrabajador.Text+"'", conexion);
```

Si el `int` resultante del `ExecuteScalar` es cero significa que no hay registro para hoy, en caso contrario existe.

```
if((int)resultado == 0)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Verifica que tengas una entrada  activa.");
 } else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Entrada  activa.");         
 }
```

Comment: Al realizar la consulta me marca un error, estuve verificando de recrearla y logre conseguirlo de la siguiente manera `                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE registroEntrada  = (select MAX(registroEntrada) AS registroEntrada from usuarios  where  numTrabajador = '"+txtTrabajador.Text+"'  and CAST (registroEntrada as date) = CAST(getdate() as date)) ", conexion` muchas gracias